# can't get ionic v4 CLI generated component to work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm currently working with the latest Ionic and I'm having a hard time trying to get a CLI generates component to work.

I start with a blank proyect and then create a new component with:

```
ionic generate component my-component
```

The command runs fine and creates the following files:

```
CREATE src/app/my-component/my-component.component.html (31 bytes)
CREATE src/app/my-component/my-component.component.spec.ts (664 bytes)
CREATE src/app/my-component/my-component.component.ts (293 bytes)
CREATE src/app/my-component/my-component.component.scss (0 bytes)
```

Then I proceed to use the new component in my main page like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
<my-component></my-component>
</ion-content>
```

The app.module.ts file is updated like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MyComponentComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When running the app in ionic lab I get the followin error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
> 'my-component' is not a known element

This is my system info:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1 
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.7.5
@angular/cli                  : 6.1.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.0.0
```

Any ideas why is this happening? I worked before with Ionic 3 and never get this problem.

update:

This is my default my-component.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: MyComponentComponent is mistake. Do you use the last version of a framework?

Comment: Can u please share MyComponent code?

Comment: I'll update my question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a custom component inside another component you have to include it in `exports` array.

```
@NgModule({
  ....
  declarations: [AppComponent, MyComponentComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  exports:[MyComponentComponent]
  ....
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can either do this way or you can make all your custom components inside another `customModule` and then import that module in `app.component.ts` page.

The name you are referring to the component is wrong. selector for your `MyComponentComponent` class is `app-my-component`, so you have to use `<app-my-component></app-my-component>` instead of `<my-component></my-component>`.

Comment: thanks! I tried that and still can't make it work k. I added the "custom element schema" to ngmodule.schemas and the error is gone but the component is not loaded either.