# How to generate a working custom component in Ionic v4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, custom-component

I'm new to Ionic, I'm using v4, I'm new to Angular and I'm new to Typescript too, so please bear with me and forgive me if I ask dumb questions. I'm on Linux.

I've started a new Ionic app with

```
$ ionic start
[...]
Project name: comptest
Framework: Angular
Starter template: tabs
[...]
```

Then I tried it:

```
$ cd comptest
$ ionic serve -l
[...]
? Install @ionic/lab? Yes
[...]
```

the browser opened up and the app worked ok. Then I tried to generate a new custom component:

```
$ ionic generate component mySpan1
[...]
[OK] Generated component!
```

That created `my-span1-component.ts` among others, which contains:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-span1',
  templateUrl: './my-span1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-span1.component.scss'],
})
export class MySpan1Component {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Please note that I edited the selector and made it look just `my-span1` instead of the default `app-my-span1`, but I didn't touch anything else, not even the html `<p>` tag that in future will become a `<span>` instead for obvious reasons. Then I tried to use `<my-span1>` in tab1 page, so I edited `tab1.page.html` and added `<my-span1>` tag:

```
<ion-content>
    <my-span1></my-span1> <!-- This is my edit -->
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
      <img src="/assets/shapes.svg" alt="" /> 
        [...]
```

After that edit the page stopped working. In the browser console I'm getting this error:

> 'my-span1' is not a known element

Googling that I found this other SO question: [Ionic 4 cannot import custom component is not a know element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253503/ionic-4-cannot-import-custom-component-is-not-a-know-element)

but the accepted answer is quite poor to say the least, and when it comes down to creating a new module I enter the unknown (for me) territory. Anyway, I tried `ionic generate module components`, and it worked, then I declared MySpan1Component in that new module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MySpan1Component } from '../my-span1/my-span1.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MySpan1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

Then I imported the new module into the app module, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, ComponentsModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but I still get the same error in the console, e.g. `'my-span1' is not a known element`. And I don't know what to do next.

Another question I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808342/cant-get-ionic-v4-cli-generated-component-to-work) suggests the same solution, or to add my component to the `exports` array: tried that too, but no luck (same error in the console):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { MySpan1Component } from './my-span1/my-span1.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MySpan1Component],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, /*ComponentsModule*/],
  exports: [MySpan1Component],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What am I missing in my code that would make `my-span1` work?

Comment: I suggest you to upload this to a working stackblitz. 
But from my perspective, are you importing the component where you are using it? 
In which component are you using `my-span1` ?

Comment: I've not found how to upload the project into stackblitz. I'm using `<my-span1>` in the tab1 page, see half down the question text. Importing it or not in the tab1.page.ts seems not to make a difference.

Comment: Could you please paste your tab1 .ts component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track:

- create new app: ionic start my-new-app
- generate new component: ionic generate my-span1
- add it to your tab1.page.module as import + add to declarations

Like so:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';

import { MySpan1CompComponent } from '../my-span1-comp/my-span1-comp.component'; // add this import statement to the module within which you intend to use your new component

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page, MySpan1CompComponent] // add your component in here 
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```